# Rails Deployment with capistrano and start resque workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, resque, rbenv, capistrano3

I'm using capistrano 3.2.1 with capistrano-resque gem to restart rasque workers on deployment. Always getting this error.

If I start workers manually under current directory on production server it starts fine.

```
cd /home/azureuser/apps/app_production/current && ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.1 /usr/bin/env nohup RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.1 ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake RACK_ENV=production RAILS_ENV=production QUEUE="mailer" PIDFILE=/home/azureuser/apps/app_production/shared/tmp/pids/resque_work_1.pid BACKGROUND=yes VERBOSE=1 INTERVAL=5 environment resque:work >> log/resque.log 2>> log/resque.log )
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as azureuser@thesend.cloudapp.net: nohup exit status: 127
nohup stdout: Nothing written
nohup stderr: Nothing written
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:16:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
SSHKit::Command::Failed: nohup exit status: 127
```

Comment: What gets written to `apps/app_production/current/log/resque.log` when it fails?

Comment: ohup: failed to run command `RBENV_ROOT=/home/azureuser/.rbenv': No such file or directory. This is the error log.

Comment: And if I check 'which rbenv' it logs '/home/azureuser/.rbenv/bin/rbenv'

Comment: The shell command being generated by capistrano-resque is invalid. It seems to me that there is an incompatibility between capistrano-resque and capistrano-rbenv, such that it generates `nohup RBENV_ROOT=...` which is a bad command. I suggest you open an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/sshingler/capistrano-resque

Comment: @MattBrictson submitted github issue. https://github.com/sshingler/capistrano-resque/issues/101. Do you have alternative suggestion for getting this done. (restart resque workers on cap deployment)?

Comment: Downgrading to 0.2.1 helps as a workaround

Comment: I downgraded to 0.2.1 and worked. This issue is discussed on https://github.com/sshingler/capistrano-resque/issues/101

Answer (score 0):

After I worked out that capistrano-rbenv was the problem, I removed that gem from my gemfile and also my capfile.

I then just added the following to my deploy.rb file:

```
set :default_env, {
  PATH: "$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH",
  RBENV_ROOT: '~/.rbenv',
  RBENV_VERSION: '2.2.2'
}
```

Now capistrano-resque works correctly as does unicorn etc..

Answer (score 0):

I fix this based on the @archfish recommendation on capistrano-resque [incompatibility between capistrano-resque and capistrano-rbenv issue](https://github.com/sshingler/capistrano-resque/issues/101#issuecomment-250354005). Then you should add or modify the `:rbenv_prefix` on deploy.rb, like:

```
set :rbenv_prefix, "env RBENV_ROOT=#{fetch(:rbenv_path)} RBENV_VERSION=#{fetch(:rbenv_ruby)} #{fetch(:rbenv_path)}/bin/rbenv exec"
```

Note: the `:rbenv_prefix` usually is used like:

```
set :rbenv_prefix, "RBENV_ROOT=#{fetch(:rbenv_path)} RBENV_VERSION=fetch(:rbenv_ruby)} #{fetch(:rbenv_path)}/bin/rbenv exec"
```